# Adding web map to Wordpress?

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web, wordpress

I'm asking a question which has already been touched upon in the two questions below. But from a slightly different angle.

I have one openlayers webmap produced in qgis 3.0 which I would like to display on my wordpress blog. I have seen suggestions here which suggest using cartoDB or another plugin but I am on the free version of Wordpress and don't have the funds to pay a large monthly subscription (I'm a hobby mapmaker so don't have any money coming in from the work). Other older posts here have suggested hosting the html code on google drive but that no longer works either.

Does anybody have any sugestions for this?

The map is of early-modern european witch trials so if anyone has a suggestion of a site/blog who would host it I'd be interested to know as well.

Two earlier questions with a similar topic:

- [Adding ArcGIS Online Webmap to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309571/adding-arcgis-online-webmap-to-qgis)
- [Embedding qgis2web exports into WordPress?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185180/embedding-qgis2web-exports-into-wordpress)

Comment: look at the accepted answer for this question

Comment: I already looks at these but the question I'm asking here refers to specifically wordpress without plugin support (free plan) which is why I asked a new question. The other question also comes from 2016 and wordpress has had some polciy changes since then

Comment: there seems to be no reason not to use the accepted answer (qgis2web) in the free plan. If there is you need to edit your question to make it clear why you can't use that path

Comment: The accepted answer says "If you are using a wordpress.com site...you'll have to find a place to host the QGIS2Web project" -- Is that the problem with that answer @stacy?